# How to verify if an Array contains data, if yes > can't overwrite it

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a code for a battleship game between user and computer, first I request the user locations to place their ships & grenades (each takes 1 spot) & can't have 2 ships or 2 grenades in the same spot.

How can I write a code that verifies if an array location is already 'occupied' and if it is to request the user to try again.

I tried to write : but obviously I can't do !null. So, I'm not sure what to write

```
public void gridverification(String[][] grid){

for(int i =0; i<grid.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j<grid.length; i++){

        if(grid[i][j] == !null){

        }
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if it's confusing(the code displayed is in my battleship class and the rest of my code is in the driver.

EDIT: I've corrected this issue, However, the message keeps getting displayed no matter what the user enters.

Here's my driver code:

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){

```
        System.out.print("Enter the coordinate of your ship #"+(i+1)+":");
        answer = keyboard.next();
        verify.gridverification(gridfinal);
        precolumn = answer.charAt(0);
        column = letter.convert(precolumn);
        prerow = Character.digit(answer.charAt(1), 10);
        row = number.convertnum(prerow);
        gridfinal[column][row] = " s ";

    }
```

Here's the verification method I made:

public void gridverification(String[][] grid){

```
if (grid != null && grid.length > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; j++)
        {

            if (grid[i][j] != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, coordinates already used. Try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (grid[i][j] != null) {`

Comment: Inner `for`, it is not `i++`, but `j++` instead

Comment: What data type is grid an array of?

Comment: Thanks... Wow such a simple syntax issue...

Comment: It is a String data

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you are doing, but if all  you are doing is checking if the spot the user specified is empty you do not need to loop through the whole array.

Comment: @WilliamV I was having such a big problem but your comment helped, I changed my verification process to verify simply what the user is entering lol thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to check if the user has already placed a ship at the location they have entered. Your current code doesn't do this. It looks over the entire array and checks if each position is empty. If they have entered a ship already, it will find it and say they need to try again. What you can do check just the position they entered. so you could do something similar to the following:

```
public String[][] populateWithShips(String[][] grid){
    int shipCount = 6;
    for (int shipIndex = 0; shipIndex < shipCount; shipIndex++) {
        boolean shipExists = false;
        while(shipExists != true){//Another way you could do this is (!shipExists)
            System.out.println("Please enter the column number for ship number " + shipIndex + :");
            int column = Integer.parseInt(this.keyboard.next());//This will take the input String and parse it to a Integer object
            System.out.println("Please enter the row number for ship number " + shipIndex + :");
            int row = Integer.parseInt(this.keyboard.next());
            //Note I haven't verified that this inputs are correct, just assuming they user enter good inputs

            if(grid[column][row] != null){
                System.out.println("Sorry, coordinates already used. Try again.\n");
            }
            else{
                grid[column][row] = " s ";
                shipExists = true;
            }
        }   
    }
    return grid;
}
```

Do note that `grid[row][column]` to be more accurate, but as long as you are consistent than it shouldn't matter.

Also, it seems that this might be a part of a homework assignment, so I recommend you read over [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems). I also recommend you use a debugger and write out the steps that you are trying to achieve. This will help you get a clearer view of what it is you are doing and makes it easier to detect mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help- Also thank you for posting the open letter, also I'm not sure where can I find such a debugger? I'm writing my code on Intelij IDEA

Answer (score 0):

You have your logic out of order. Write it as `if(grid[i][j] != null)`. This way you are seeing if the grid at the location is **not equal** to null.

Comment: you made a typo "!=="

Answer (score 0):

you should check the given grid array and the actual element at [i][j]. You can additionally check the size of the element like `((grid[i][j] != null) && (grid[i][j].length() > 0))`

```
public void gridverification(String[][] grid) {
    if (grid != null && grid.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid.length; i++) {
                if (grid[i][j] != null) {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you are working on a big project where you oftenly need to check string variable's being null and its size then you should use `StringUtils.isEmpty` or `StringUtils.isNotBlank` by adding `commons-lang-2-6.jar` as dependency jar in your project.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html

Comment: I tried that, if that condition is true, I want it to display to the user "Sorry, the coordinates already used, try again" However, even when it's a new value, it keeps displaying the message...I've updated my initial question with the code

Comment: You should capture the intial array in another array which can be used to compare with the new values in the new array, if they are same then alert user else continue with processing as they are new values.